# Editing UI of Samvera Hyrax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to customize the UI of Samvera Hyrax application and I've built a HTML template. Now, I want to replace the old UI with the content of my HTML files, when I say it on github I found view files where I can edit the application to implement my design. But after installing I could not find any files under views. Though I found **application.html.erb.**

I cannot figure out where `<%= yeild %>` has been pointing and when I replaced all the content with my home page code. It made no changes in the hyrax working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you followed the Hyrax installation procedure detailed on the github wiki [here](https://github.com/samvera/hyrax#creating-a-hyrax-based-app), what you'll notice looking at your routes in `config/routes.rb` is that Hyrax is mounted as a rails engine.  So using the template you didn't clone Hyrax, but you created a new rails app that uses Hyrax as an Engine. If you haven't used Engines before, it may be worth reading up on them [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).  This is why you don't see all the views from the Hyrax project in the application you've generated using their template.

You can override views from the Engine by creating the `view` in your own project in the same path as it is in Hyrax.  You may want to do some additional digging to determine if this is a path you really want to go down, as it can get complicated to maintain overridden views, and there may be alternative strategies that can accomplish some of what you want to do with CSS or themeing within Hyrax.  It may depend on how much you want to override and how custom a theme you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. My customization is not limited to just CSS, my project needs to change the complete theme and even to play with the results from the database. Unfortunately, there is no API documentation for the Hyrax so I have to face the complications.

Comment: I've another Idea,what do you think about editing the view files before installation so that it would be easy. But to check the changes I might have to install it lot of times.

Comment: It would not be unusual to override views in the generated app, I guess I was just pointing out the maintenance of it.

Comment: Thanks mike that was really helpful. I have changed the views part of the Hyrax, and I know we have to edit the homepage controller and the CRUD of hyrax is not in typical ruby syntax but it is linked to solr. So, I have tried looking in to Solr for field 'date_uploaded' as mentioned in the file